# How to connect an already existing .Net Core application to Azure SQL Database with managed identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

What are the steps to successfully connect the application to Azure SQL Database after setting up the connection string and adding the App Authentication NuGet package.

Comment: What have you tried? What practical problem are you facing? Where is your code? P.s. I'm assuming you've done some basic research and found a tutorial like this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-dotnet-core or something similar? If not, why not?

Comment: I did find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi but i am looking for something in .Netcore without entity framework.

Comment: I am stuck and I am unable to find AccessToken method under SqlConnection. How to open the connection to Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Follow the tutorial I linked you to. It uses .NET Core and ADO.NET

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to use managed identity (using access token)?

Comment: @user215 Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept the answer？

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Azure Managed Identity to connect Azure SQL database in .Net Core MVC project, We can use the package [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) with SqlConnection.AccessToken.

The detailed steps are as below.

1. Create MSI
2. Configure SQL Database

   a. [Use your Azure Sql AD admin to connect Azure SQL vai SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell)

   b. Add the MSI to the database you need use

   ```
   USE [<db name>]
   GO
   create user [<your msi name>] from external provider
   ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [<function app name>]
   ```
3. Code

```
 /*
             Install SDK Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

*/

 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            List<StarWar> starWars = new List<StarWar>();
            var connectionString = "Server=tcp:<server-name>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<database-name>;";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.AccessToken = await (new Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                var sql = "SELECT  * FROM [dbo].[StarWars]";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            StarWar starWar = new StarWar();
                            starWar.episode = Convert.ToInt32(reader["episode"]);
                            starWar.score = Convert.ToInt32(reader["score"]);
                            starWar.name = Convert.ToString(reader["name"]);
                            starWars.Add(starWar);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


                return View(starWars);
        }
```

[image]